# Send-MailMessage closes every 2nd connection when using attachments

Tags: powershell, email, smtp, smtpclient

I am attempting to write a powershell script to send email with a few attachments to 30 people. The emails are personalized, so they must be sent individually. The script works just fine without attachments. However, when using attachments, every other instance of Send-MailMessage fails with:

> Send-MailMessage : Unable to write data to the transport connection:
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**It does not seem to matter how long I wait/pause between sending messages.** Even if I wait several minutes, the first instance will always succeed, the next will fail, the next will succeed, etc.. I've even noticed between running scripts, that my ctrl+c on even or odd numbers determines the success of the first instance of Send-MailMessage. If the last message fails, the first succeeds, and vice versa.

My code is very simple, we just have a single array with all the users, and

```
$array | foreach {
  Write-Host "Sending Mail..."
  Send-MailMessage -From 'myemail@domain' -To $_.EmailAddress 
  -SmtpServer 'fqdn' 
  -Attachments "1.pdf", "2.pdf"
  -Subject 'Subject'
  -Body ($html)
  -BodyAsHtml
}
```

So the output will be something along the lines of:

> Sending Mail...
>
> Sending Mail...
>
> Send-MailMessage : Unable to write data to the transport connection:
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> Sending Mail...
>
> Sending Mail...
>
> Send-MailMessage : Unable to write data to the transport connection:
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

And in the instances where there are no errors, the mail arrives perfectly intact.

I can "fix" this by just doing:

```
try { Send-MailMessage ... -EA Stop }
catch { Send-MailMessage }
```

And as a result, 30/30 people will receive the mail (rather than 15/30), since every single try (besides #1) fails but the code in the catch block is always able to succeed.

Of course, this isn't a real solution and I would hate to leave it like that. Does anyone have any insight into what is going on here, and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like your outbound mail server has some tight restrictions on # of active connections from a single source IP? I think your workaround is a not terrible solution, I did a quick google and there's no obvious way to manually force close your connections, other than hitting the limit which seemingly triggers the server to kill them.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4fhm8z/close_smtp_connection_between_sendmailmessage/

Comment: Does that explain why there are only issues when I use attachments, though? I am not aware of any limits on this server, I can take away the attachments and send hundreds of emails in seconds and have no issues whatsoever. I think this same server sent out 50k+ emails just yesterday from one IP.

Comment: If that limit was an issue he would not be able to send the first one.

Comment: Good point. It's a really interesting issue, I hope someone else is able to offer a better explanation, google is coming up pretty blank for me.

Comment: @Matt is correct. There is no limit that I am aware of, but either way we're talking about two ~2mb pdf files, that shouldn't be an issue for this server.

Comment: I would be tempted to read the smtp logs from the server just to see if there is anything there. Otherwise I like the idea of adding everyone to the one mail but bcc'd

Comment: I will try to take a look at the SMTP server, but adding everyone to one email is not an option, there are parameters in the message that need to be personalized for each user.

Comment: Is this exchange then? What version? Or else what is the SMTP host?

Comment: @MacroPower That is fair. I would add that into the question as that is an important limitation.

Comment: PowerShell jobs have their own memory and resources. When the job is done that memory is supposed to be removed. Does not help if it is a remote issue but I wonder if you could create a job for each mail and wait for that... that won't I think. Can't tell when the process is complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I have found the best available solution to this. Big thanks to Matt for helping me with this in the comments.

It seems like the issue spawns from `Send-Mailmessage` not properly disposing the connection object once it finishes sending mail. Running `Send-Mailmessage` with an existing connection forces it to be disposed, and thus running it for a third time results in success.

The workaround is running each instance of `Send-Mailmessage` as a separate job. To [quote Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349726/send-mailmessage-closes-every-2nd-connection-when-using-attachments#comment73764602_43349726):

> PowerShell jobs have their own memory and resources. When the job is
> done that memory is supposed to be removed.

As a result, each time we run `Send-Mailmessage` as a job, the connection is properly created and disposed. I am also piping this to `Wait-Job | Receive-Job` to naturally rate-limit, view output, and prevent any memory issues that could maybe be theoretically possible.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  Send-MailMessage -From 'mymail' -To 'theirmail' -SmtpServer 'fqdn' -Attachments "$($args[0])\1.pdf", "$($args[0])\2.pdf" -Subject 'subject' -Body ("test")
} -ArgumentList $PSScriptRoot | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Using this method produces no errors, and should reduce load on the SMTP server.

Comment: You guys saved me. For completion : Wanted to send log file but when `Send-Mailmessage` was in error (i.e. smtp error from server), the log file was inaccessible "is being used" after.

Comment: @Boop That sounds like a completely separate issue: you still had the log file open when you tried to interact with it a second time.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to indicate a transport layer issue. Without knowing your network architecture it's a little tough to know for sure. Try this:

Maybe add a wait to your foreach loop to see if there is a server that is throttling (for lack of better word) your messages. Without access to the server config, your hack is likely the best you can do with this.

As far as your try/catch solution, that is going to produce the fastest success on your end, however, it will increase network traffic. You are essentially brute forcing your way past whatever limits you are hitting.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Like I mentioned, wait times do not seem to correct this at all. I am not too worried about putting load on the server, however, so a brute-force that at max doubles my connection attempts isn't a huge issue. I just hate the inelegance of doing that, putting a script into production that is guaranteed to fail ~50% of its connection attempts...

Comment: Totally get that. I cringe at leaving it there as well, but at the end of the day, you found something that works. SMTP is its own animal. Hopefully a SMTP neck-beard will chime in.