# Long delay before email arrives after PowerShell Send-MailMessage command (~2 and a half minutes)

Tags: powershell, email, smtp

I'm writing a PowerShell script to check multiple PCs for specific files and send an email if it finds them. It works, but the email takes a very long time to arrive (roughly two and a half minutes). I've tried running just the Send-MailMessage command and gotten the same results, so it isn't a different part of the script slowing it down. And it's not crunching for all that time - the command succeeds immediately. Outlook sends and receives other emails in this building much faster, and I've checked which SMTP server it's using and used the same one. I searched for anyone else having this problem, but only found examples of Send-MailMessage timing out or not working at all.

This is the command I've been using (to/from/smtp server replaced with placeholders):

```
Send-MailMessage -To "Example Person <ex@example.com>" -From "Example Person <ex@example.com>" -Subject "Test mail" -SmtpServer "XXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.com" -dno onFailure, onSuccess, Delay
```

I should note that when I run this, -dno Delay doesn't notify me that the email was delayed (and isn't the source of the problem itself, since when I take out the dno parameters I get the same results). Instead I get a success notification two and a half minutes later, when it arrives.

Comment: I'd check the SMTP server first. Maybe it has some built in delay to scare off unknown senders for instance. My experience with Send-MailMessage is that messages are sent and delivered instantly

Comment: have you checked the headers in the received message? see how many servers it passed thru, or see if it shows spam test tags that are different from what your sent-by-Outlook mails show, OR any other differences.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was the first google result I wanted to provide an answer - As [this post implies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43376883/2554363) Powershell doesn't close the TCP connection immediately after sending, which can leave the SMTP session open or something.

However, if you end the PS Session then it closes the connection. Running as a script block closes immediately, like below:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    # specify arguments to send-mailmessage as argument hash below, then splat
    $mailArgs = $args[0];
    Send-MailMessage @mailArgs;
} -ArgumentList @(@{
    To = "Example Person <ex@example.com>";
    From = "Example Person <ex@example.com>";
    Subject = "Test mail";
    SmtpServer = "XXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.com";
    dno = @('onFailure', 'onSuccess', 'Delay');
});
# wait for job to complete (timeout after 30 seconds)
wait-job $job -Timeout 30;
# get result of job (if any)
receive-job $job;
```